# Finding smallest number >= x not present in the given sorted array

Tags: c++, sorting, binary-search

I am having difficulty writing a modified binary search algorithm that returns the smallest number greater than or equal to X which is **not** present in the sorted array.

For example, if the array is `{1,2,3,5,6}` and `x = 2` then answer is 4. Please guide me how to write the binary search for this. I have to answer this in O(log n) time for each x. Since I am taking this array as input which will initially take linear time, you may do some kind of preprocessing on the array initially if you want.

x is also taken as input and may or may not be present in the array.

The input array may have repeating elements.

My input numbers can be in the range [0,10^9] and hence first putting all the missing values in the array is not feasible because of space constraints.

Also, you can do preprocessing which takes O(n) time since you are taking the array as input in linear time. After that, there will be let us say 10^6 queries of X, which you have to answer, each in O(log n) time

Comment: You can judge if elements of sorted array are continuous (like `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`) by checking if the number of elements is `(the rightmost element) - (the leftmost element) + 1`,.

Comment: Is your array sorted or may it not?

Comment: it is given sorted, but may have repeating elements

Comment: Transform input into "segment": `{1,2,3,5,6}` -> `{{1,3} ,{5,6}}`, then `lower_bound` might select correct segment.

Comment: @Jarod42 I am liking this idea, but could you tell what value do I search for lower_bound? something like {X, +INF} would do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are allowed to do any kind of preprocessing and only finding the result for different `x` must be `O(log n)`. If thats the case finding the result after preprocessing isn't a big deal. `O(log n)` search algorithms do exist. Good candidates are `std::binary_search` or `std::lower_bound`.

A very naive approach is to prepare a vector with all missing elements and then `std::lower_bound` on that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> input{1,2,3,5,6,10,12};
    std::vector<int> missing_elements{4,7,8,9,11};
    int x = 2;
    auto it = std::lower_bound(missing_elements.begin(),missing_elements.end(),x);
    std::cout << *it << "\n";
}
```

Populating `missing_elements` can be done in `O(1)`. However, a `missing_elements` with a size of the order of `10^9` is of course not feasible. Also this approach is extremely wasteful for input like `[1,100000000]` (not in terms of time complexity, but in terms of runtime and memory usage).

---

An idea put up by Jarod42 in a comment is to prepare a vector of segments and then `std::lower_bound` on that. First assuming preprocessing has already been done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int find_first_missing(const std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>& segments,int x){
    std::pair<int,int> p{x,x};
    auto it = std::lower_bound(segments.begin(),segments.end(),p,[](auto a,auto b){
        return a.second < b.second;
    });
    if (it == segments.end()) return x;
    if (it->first > x) return x;    
    return it->second+1;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> input{1,2,3,5,6,10,12};
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> segments{{1,3},{5,6},{10,10},{12,12}};
    for (int x=0; x<13;++x) std::cout << x << " -> " << find_first_missing(segments,x) << "\n";
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/WrnP9s6GT):

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 4
2 -> 4
3 -> 4
4 -> 4
5 -> 7
6 -> 7
7 -> 7
8 -> 8
9 -> 9
10 -> 11
11 -> 11
12 -> 13
```

Because `input` is sorted, and `segments` is sorted, we can use a custom comparator that only compares the end of the segment. The vector of segments is also sorted with respect to that comparator. The call to `lower_bound` returns an iterator to the segment where either `x` is inside or `x` is lower than the segment, hence `if (it->first > x) return x;` otherwise we know that `it->second+1` is the next missing number.

---

Now it is only left to create the vector of segments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> segment(const std::vector<int>& input){
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> result;
    if (input.size() == 0) return result;
    
    int current_start = input[0];
    for (int i=1;i<input.size();++i){
        if (input[i-1] == input[i] || input[i-1]+1 == input[i]) continue;
        result.push_back({current_start,input[i-1]});
        current_start = input[i];        
    }
    result.push_back({current_start,input.back()});
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> input{1,2,3,5,6,10,12};
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> expected{{1,3},{5,6},{10,10},{12,12}};
    auto result = segment(input);
    for (const auto& e : result){
        std::cout << e.first << " " << e.second << "\n";
    }
    assert(expected == result);
}
```

Comment: "It can be done in linear time" My input is {1, 1000000000000}, go ahead.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I guess you are just making fun of me. A `O(1)` check for sane input can be added and for pathological input like yours finding the result is also only `O(1)`. I find it silly to focus on complexity. Unless one has to design a general purpose algorithm library, complexity is largely irrelevant. I guess its just an effect of academical exercises. If I had to write production code for this problem I would want to know the time constraints and more info about the input, whether then I use `O(n^2)` or `O(log n)` is rather secondary.

Comment: "A O(1) check for sane input can be added" Try to add it then, and I will break it. "I find it silly to focus on complexity." Then perhaps say so in the answer, because the question clearly focuses on complexity and expects the answer to do the same. Anyway, there is a working preprocessing suggestion in the comments: preprocess to intervals. You could preprocess to missing intervals as well.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. but the answer does focus on complexity. It is possible to get missing numbers for  `{1, 1000000000000}` in linear time and "If I understand correctly, you are allowed to do any kind of preprocessing and only finding the result for different x must be O(log n)"

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. dont get me wrong, I like to get challenged and I appreciate any critic, but I am afraid I don't get your point. Getting `missing_elements` in linear time was just a side remark, because as I understood the answer `O(log n)` is only required for anything after the preprocessing

Comment: You said you can check for pathological input in O(1) which is not possible, You can do it in O(n) preprocessing time of course. Just build an array of intervals (of existing numbers or of gaps, doesn't matter). I was just picking nits.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. ok, no worries. I agree that more thought can be put into a solution than I did when I wrote the answer. I might come back to this later. Jarods suggestion in the comment sounds interesting.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. oh and I almost forgot, thanks for the feedback, appreciated :)

Comment: Let me give some more clarity  : First, my input numbers can be in the range [0,10^9] and hence first putting all the missing values in the array is not feasible because of space constraints. Secondly, you can do preprocessing which takes O(n) time since you are taking the array as input in linear time. After that, there will be let us say 10^5 queries of X, which you have to answer, each in O(log n) time

Comment: @AbhinavSinghal please add such requirements/constraints in the question

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I feel stupid now for my rant against complexity. To some degree I still stand to what I wrote, what matters is runtime while complexity is kind of secondary, but such hairsplitting is irrelvant when input size is in the order of `10^9`. When I said `O(1)` sanity check i was thinking of using front, back and size to see whether searching in missing elements is feasible, though of course defending against one pathological case does not match every other. With respect to that I was on the wrong track too. How about cleaning up the comments?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number You are a hero! That should work let me try. My only doubt is `if (it->first > x) return x;` in this line, what if `it == segments.end()` ?

Comment: @AbhinavSinghal thats a case I didnt consider. I'll have to take a break now, if you can fix it, feel free to edit the answer. Btw it isnt very heroic to give away not thoroughly tested code. Also, I don't want SO to be a code writing service and I didnt do that idea a great favor by writing this answer.

Comment: @AbhinavSinghal the canonical saying goes like this: "give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime". This answer is a fish with at least one error

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thanks for fixing the bug... I was successfully able to do what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

If `x` is not present in the array then return `x`.

If `x` is present, say it's at position `l`. Also, let's denote `missing(i)` to be the number of elements missing to the left of `i`. In a 1-indexed array, this equals `A[i]-i`. Then keep moving right from `l` until `missing(i) - missing(l) = 0`. You can use modified binary search for this. Suppose `p` is the position of the last element where `missing(p) - missing(l) = 0` then `A[p]+1` is the first missing number greater than `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int greaterValue(const vector<int>& elements, int x){
        int low = 0, 
            high = elements.size() -1, 
            answer = x + 1;
        
        while (low <= high) {
            int mid = (low + high) / 2;
            if (elements[mid] <= answer) {
                if (elements[mid] == answer) {
                    answer++;
                    high = elements.size() - 1;
                }
                low = mid + 1;
            }
            else {
                high = mid - 1;
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }
    
    int main() {
        vector<int> elements = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 };
        int x = 2;
        int result = greaterValue(elements, x);
        cout << "The element is: " << result;
        return 0;
    }
```

Test:

```
    { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 }
```

Result:

```
    The element is: 4
```

Time complexity:

```
    O(log(n))
```

Comment: This program [doesn't work](https://godbolt.org/z/rKeMWTEjx).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  for your input ({ 1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5,9 }) is: 3 Properly.

Comment: The output is "Element is present at index 3", what does it mean? Perhaps it is just wrong output and it should read "The absent element is 3"? Then take a lok at [this modified version](https://godbolt.org/z/YoEznEvT4). I only added step counting.

Comment: Not sure it is `O(log(n))`, as you are looking for each element. (Look like `O(n log(n))` for me).

Comment: The algorithm is correct. Basically when `answer` is not in `elements`, it'll return `answer` but if it's present, binary search first finds it, sets `low` to next position and `high` to last position and starts binary search again. Consider `A = [1, 2, 3, ..., n]`, for `1` it will be called `log(n)` times, `2` it will be called `log(n-1)` times and so on. This is bounded by `O(nlog(n))`.